# How to flatten JSON object to pandas Dataframe object

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list having multiple items

```
result = *json_formatted*
print(result) <-- [{'id: 1', value: array([10,11,12])}, {id: 2, value: array([20,21,22]) }]
```

I am struggling to get this as a dataframe. 
I'd like my output to look like

```
id value
1 10
1 11
1 12
2 20
2 21
2 22
```

Comment: is your json format valid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering this to be your `result`:

```
In [940]: import numpy as np
In [941]: result = [{'id': 1, 'value': np.array([10,11,12])}, {'id': 2, 'value': np.array([20,21,22]) }]
```

You can use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html): (available in pandas version > 0.25, as @Shijith pointed out)

```
In [952]: import pandas as pd
In [946]: df = pd.DataFrame(result)
In [950]: df = df.explode('value')

In [951]: df
Out[951]: 
   id value
0   1    10
0   1    11
0   1    12
1   2    20
1   2    21
1   2    22
```

Comment: if pandas version > 0.25

Comment: Oh that is right. Have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Check your version of `pandas`.

Comment: just `print(pd.__version__)` to check the pandas version

Comment: mine is 0.23.4, I will upgrade it now cheers